# Configuring Jetty to do console-capture and requestlog to a directory outside of jetty.base?

Tags: jetty

Looking at the docs, all the logging paths specified for console-capture and requestlog are relative to jetty.base, normally in `$jetty.base/logs` . That's ok for many purposes but, I really want logs to go into /var/logs/jetty , just like a lot of other processes would do. I've tried setting this in console-capture as `/var/log/jetty`, but that just tries to save log files in `$jetty.base/var/log/jetty`, which isn't what I need.

Is there some way to do this? I'm looking for the simplest possible approaches to saving logs. This is the last thing I need to do before my Jetty installation is fully in production. Overall it's been great. This is all with Jetty 9, latest release, on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Start by not using `console-capture`.

You have progressed beyond the limited scope of `console-capture` with your requirement.

You'll want a formal logging framework, pick one, like "logback" (which the Jetty devs recommend), or java.util.logging, or log4j.

Use one of the `logging-*` modules to setup Jetty's server classpath to start using that logging library.

Now configure that logging library (example: if you are using "logback", the file `${jetty.base}/resources/logback.xml` is what you configure)

Finally, configure your access logging to use slf4j.

Boom, all of your logging is now going to your logging library of choice, and it's configuration can be used to slice / dice / roll over / filter / etc the logging in any way you want.

You can have it split into different logging output files, combine them into one, roll on different rules (size, number of lines, duration, time, etc).

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer. There's a logback-access module which includes a configuration file which is `resources/logback-access.xml`. Edit that file and specify a filename anywhere and it works. I also changed the log pattern from combined to the string which is equal to combined plus %D to get the latency value.

Comment: The suggestion I have provided here is far newer then the old logback-access techniques.  The new [CustomRequestLog](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/server/CustomRequestLog.html) features within Jetty are far more capable then logback-access.

Comment: But what if I don't really want a custom request log? Really I will be happy if I can put combined log format files somewhere in /var/log, just like web servers have been doing for the past 20+ years. I'm still not following exactly which modules I should activate. I'm right now trying to get logback.xml configured but something isn't working with it. I like that Jetty has all these options but I wish it had some more sensible defaults. Getting log files into /var/log should be easy, not hard.

Comment: Then there's no need for `logback-access`, and you can just use the predefined `NCSA_FORMAT` or `EXTENDED_NCSA_FORMAT` found in the `CustomRequestLog` (which is what the [`NCSARequestLog`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/server/NCSARequestLog.html) uses anyway)

Comment: But how do I even activate `CustomRequestLog`? There's no module that corresponds to that. Surely I don't have to write Java code to simply configure it to write logs to a file? This can't be this hard can it? I did get it working with logback-access. I wish the Jetty docs would make it more clear, "this is how you do basic logging", rather than, "here are ten different options you can configure".

Comment: The module "customrequestlog" which is listed in `--list-modules` under the "requestlog" section.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely made some progress on this. For some reason, console redirect was taking the absolute path correctly while the request logger was not. For that, I made my configuration relative: `../../../var/log/jetty`
This seems like a clunky way to do it but it does seem to work. I'm still getting a failure on startup but weirdly enough it's running fine and I don't see exceptions so I need to figure that out now.